# azure container app going timeout for first request in the daily morning but after that every request is working

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-apps

I have configured minimum replicas to 1 but still it didn't help

I'm not really sure what's happening.
Note the app environment is Workload profiles. I am looking for leads as I'm bit clueless with the cold start issue in the mornings.

Comment: It is possible that your Azure Container App is experiencing a cold start issue in the mornings. By default, web apps are unloaded if they're idle for a set period of time, which can cause longer load times for the first request after the app is idle. To decrease the response time for the first request after idle time, you can turn on the Always On setting in Basic and Standard service plans. However, would require more details on this to further analyse the issue.

Comment: Check these References:

-   [Reliability in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/reliability-azure-container-apps#availability-zone-support)
-   [Application performance FAQs for Web Apps in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time)

Comment: @Arko Do  we have cold start concept in azure container apps similar to azure webapp? I'm keeping replica to 1 atleast to make container always available

Comment: Check this link- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/199

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Apps is a serverless platform, and like most serverless offerings, it can experience cold starts, although the term is more commonly associated with functions-as-a-service (FaaS) platforms like Azure Functions.

A cold start occurs when your container has to start from a completely stopped state, which happens when the service scales down to zero instances due to inactivity. However, if you've set the minimum number of replicas to 1, the service should, in theory, always have one running instance of the container, which should help mitigate cold starts.

Here are some reasons you might still experience a cold start-like behavior:

1. **Replica Setting**: Confirm that your minimum replicas setting is indeed being respected. There might be a delay if the platform is scaling from 0 to 1 replica due to some configuration issue or platform behavior.
2. **Initialization Time**: Even if the container is running, your application might be doing some initialization on the first request of the day, which could be causing the delay.
3. **Networking**: There might be networking or DNS resolution delays, especially if your container is part of a VNET or using private endpoints.

To further investigate, you should look at the metrics and logs for your container app in the Azure portal or use Azure Monitor to gain more insights into what happens overnight. This can help determine if the app is indeed scaling to zero replicas or if something else is causing the slow start.
[image]

[image]

Below is an example where I deploy an image on Azure Container App and keep the scaling similar to yours i.e. minimum 1 replica.

[image]

and as you can see, it is running fine without any delay
[image]

[image]

Therefore as I mentioned in my comments and shared a similar [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/199) with you earlier, The cold start times is depended on many factors such as image size, number of replicas or w.r.t networking DNS resolution delays.

References:

- [Application performance FAQs for Web Apps in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time)
- [Reliability in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/reliability-azure-container-apps#availability-zone-support)